# Python - Pandas dataframe - set flag at intersecting indicies to 1 and the rest to 0

Tags: python, pandas

My problem: I want to subset a pandas dataframe and set a flag column of this index to 1 and have the rest set to 0

Here is what I have:

```
sorted_pVals = pd.DataFrame(pVals.items(),columns=['Name', 'P-Val'])
sorted_pVals = sorted_pVals.sort_values("P-Val")    
sorted_pVals = sorted_pVals.reset_index(drop = True)
sorted_pVals['Flag'] = 0

listOfGenesInBoth = list(set(GeneSet2).intersection(sorted_pVals['Name'].tolist()))
sorted_pVals[sorted_pVals.Name.isin(listOfGenesInBoth)]
Out[442]: 
         Name     P-Val  Flag
24     L49229  0.000006     0
131    L49219  0.000157     0
474    M19045  0.003021     0
561   X140081  0.004169     0
```

When I do:

```
sorted_pVals[sorted_pVals.Name.isin(listOfGenesInBoth)]['Flag'] = 1
```

The values still remain 0, How can I set them to 1 at the indicies of `listOfGenesInBoth`

In R I would do something like:

```
df[GenesVec %in% df$genes] <- 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to use `loc`, whereby you are locating all rows where the name of `sorted_pVals` is in `listOfGenesInBoth`, and then set the `Flag` column to 1.

```
sorted_pVals.loc[sorted_pVals.Name.isin(listOfGenesInBoth), 'Flag'] = 1
```